# how to select the N most recent rows in a table in mysql, getting error because of "order clause"

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to select my N recent rows of my table. However I keep getting an error. I tried to use the methods that were posted around on the web, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT measurements.timestamp, 
airports.name,
CASE 
    WHEN measurements.unit = "F" THEN ROUND((measurements.temperature - 32) * 5/9,1)
    WHEN measurements.unit = "K" THEN ROUND(measurements.temperature - 273.15, 1)
ELSE measurements.temperature
END AS temperatureCelcius 
FROM measurements, airports
WHERE airports.code = measurements.airportCode
ORDER BY measurements.id DESC LIMIT 10) T ORDER BY 
T.id;
```

and this is the error message:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause
```

Comment: you have no id field in your nner Select

Comment: There is no column id defined in your subquery

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to select it in the subquery.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT m.timestamp, a.name, m.id,
             (CASE WHEN m.unit = 'F'
                   THEN ROUND((m.temperature - 32) * 5/9,1)
                   WHEN m.unit = 'K' 
                   THEN ROUND(m.temperature - 273.15, 1)
                   ELSE m.temperature
              END) AS temperatureCelcius 
      FROM measurements m JOIN
           airports a
           ON a.code = m.airportCode
      ORDER BY m.id DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) T
ORDER BY T.id;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The SQL standard for strings delimiters is the single quote, rather than the double quote.  Double quotes are also used for identifiers, so it is better to stick with single quotes.
- Always use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  No commas in the `FROM` clause.
- The indentation style starts each clause on a separate line, aligned with the rest of the query.